# How add a binding Command and command parameter to each list box item

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

please help me how to add a binding command and command parameter to each listboxItem.I create this listbox to select a country language.This is my code.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            Padding="3" Background="SkyBlue"
                            BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush"Value="OrangeRed" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background"Value="HotPink" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBoxItem Content="English" />
<ListBoxItem Content="china" IsSelected="True" />
<ListBoxItem Content="Japan" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this...

#### Way 1 - use the `ListBox`'s `SelectionChanged` event to trigger the command

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <!-- styling code left out here for brevity -->
            <ListBoxItem Content="English" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="China" IsSelected="True" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Japan" />
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp7
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.AddedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                //no item selected
                return;
            }

            //check if the data context is the view model
            if (this.DataContext is MainViewModel viewModel)
            {
                //get the first selected item
                var selectedLanguage = e.AddedItems[0];

                //execute command with the selected language as a parameter (I'm assuming that you have a view model with an ICommand property called LanguageChangedCommand here)
                if (viewModel.LanguageChangedCommand.CanExecute(selectedLanguage))
                {
                    viewModel.LanguageChangedCommand.Execute(selectedLanguage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Way 2 - bind the `ListBox`'s `SelectedItem` property and trigger the change whenever the property is changed

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}">
            <ListBoxItem Content="English" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="China" IsSelected="True" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Japan" />
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp7
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _selectedLanguage;
        public string SelectedLanguage
        {
            get => _selectedLanguage;
            set
            {
                if(_selectedLanguage == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _selectedLanguage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedLanguage));
                OnLanguageChanged(value);
            }
        }

        private void OnLanguageChanged(string newLanguage)
        {
            //do something here when the language changes
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @michel Divis thank you very much. You save my time

Comment: Hi, @Hasith Yoman. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you could click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Comment: @HasithYoman Glad I could help. If the solution worked for you, please click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer as Hui Liu mentioned.